# Qt QQuickFramebufferObject OpenGL rendering invades other object's scenes and is red

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml

I know that a minimal complete and verifiable example is generally needed, but this example cannot be broken into a smaller one because there's too much libraries needed to get and decode a video from my security camera. I hope someone can help me by pointing possible simple mistakes in rendering using QQuickFrameBufferObject.

[image]

**The two problems I'm having is that the images are RED and the image from one object invades the space of the other object in a very inexplicable way.** In the image above you can see what should be 4 different camera feeds which are instantiated through QML.

Here's the class that renders everything. YUV420P data is feeded using the `update()` function. You can see the simple shader that decodes YUV420P into RGB. Each QML object (camera stream) is one instance from this class.

[OpenGlBufferQtQuick.cpp](https://github.com/lucaszanella/orwell/blob/4fddecd5c6e233519489b61d57aaee14f39db53c/OpenGlBufferQtQuick.cpp):

```
#include "OpenGlBufferQtQuick.h"
#include <QOpenGLFramebufferObjectFormat>
#include <QRunnable>
#include <QEventLoop>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QMutexLocker>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <QTimer>

#define GET_STR(x) #x
#define A_VER 3
#define T_VER 4

static const GLfloat ver[] = {
    -1.0f,-1.0f,
     1.0f,-1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f,
     1.0f, 1.0f
};

static const GLfloat tex[] = {
    0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 0.0f
};

//Simple shader. Outpus the same location as input, I guess
const char *vString3 = GET_STR(
    attribute vec4 vertexIn;
    attribute vec2 textureIn;
    varying vec2 textureOut;
    uniform mat4 u_transform;   
    void main(void)
    {
        gl_Position = u_transform * vertexIn;
        textureOut = textureIn;
    }
);


//The matrix below does YUV420P to RGB conversion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y%E2%80%B2UV420p_(and_Y%E2%80%B2V12_or_YV12)_to_RGB888_conversion
//This texture shader replaces the color of the pixel with the new color, but in RGB. (I guess)
const char *tString3 = GET_STR(
    varying vec2 textureOut;
    uniform sampler2D tex_y;
    uniform sampler2D tex_u;
    uniform sampler2D tex_v;
    void main(void)
    {
        vec3 yuv;
        vec3 rgb;
        yuv.x = texture2D(tex_y, textureOut).r;
        yuv.y = texture2D(tex_u, textureOut).r - 0.5;
        yuv.z = texture2D(tex_v, textureOut).r - 0.5;
        rgb = mat3(1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
            0.0, -0.39465, 2.03211,
            1.13983, -0.58060, 0.0) * yuv;
        gl_FragColor = vec4(rgb, 1.0);
    }

);


OpenGlBufferItemRenderer::OpenGlBufferItemRenderer(string uri){
    this->uri = uri;
}


void OpenGlBufferItemRenderer::render() {
    QOpenGLFunctions *f = QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->functions();
    if (firstFrameReceived) {
        if (this->firstRender) {
            std::cout << "Creating QOpenGLShaderProgram " << std::endl;
            program = new QOpenGLShaderProgram();
            f->initializeOpenGLFunctions();
            //this->m_F  = QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->functions();
            std::cout << "frameWidth: " << frameWidth << + " frameHeight: " << frameHeight << std::endl;

            std::cout << "Fragment Shader compilation: " << program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, tString3) << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Vertex Shader compilation: " << program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, vString3) << std::endl;

            program->bindAttributeLocation("vertexIn",A_VER);
            program->bindAttributeLocation("textureIn",T_VER);
            std::cout << "program->link() = " << program->link() << std::endl;

            f->glGenTextures(3, texs);//TODO: ERASE THIS WITH glDeleteTextures
            this->firstRender = false;
        }

        // Not strictly needed for this example, but generally useful for when
        // mixing with raw OpenGL.
        //m_window->resetOpenGLState();//COMMENT OR NOT?

        program->bind();

        QMatrix4x4 transform;
        transform.setToIdentity();
        program->setUniformValue("u_transform", transform);

        f->glVertexAttribPointer(A_VER, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, ver);
        f->glEnableVertexAttribArray(A_VER);

        f->glVertexAttribPointer(T_VER, 2, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, tex);
        f->glEnableVertexAttribArray(T_VER);

        unis[0] = program->uniformLocation("tex_y");
        unis[1] = program->uniformLocation("tex_u");
        unis[2] = program->uniformLocation("tex_v");

        //Y
        f->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[0]);
        f->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        f->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        f->glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, frameWidth, frameHeight, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

        //U
        f->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[1]);
        f->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        f->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        f->glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, frameWidth/2, frameHeight / 2, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

        //V
        f->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[2]);
        f->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        f->glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        f->glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, frameWidth / 2, frameHeight / 2, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

        f->glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        f->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[0]);
        f->glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, datas[0]);
        f->glUniform1i(unis[0], 0);


        f->glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+1);
        f->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[1]); 
        f->glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, frameWidth/2, frameHeight / 2, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, datas[1]);
        f->glUniform1i(unis[1],1);


        f->glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+2);
        f->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[2]);
        f->glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, frameWidth / 2, frameHeight / 2, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, datas[2]);
        f->glUniform1i(unis[2], 2);

        f->glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP,0,4);

        program->disableAttributeArray(A_VER);
        program->disableAttributeArray(T_VER);
        program->release();

    } 
    update();
}

QOpenGLFramebufferObject *OpenGlBufferItemRenderer::createFramebufferObject(const QSize &size)
{
    QOpenGLFramebufferObjectFormat format;
    format.setAttachment(QOpenGLFramebufferObject::CombinedDepthStencil);
    //format.setSamples(16);
    return new QOpenGLFramebufferObject(size, format);
}
//https://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/05/11/integrating-custom-opengl-rendering-with-qt-quick-via-qquickframebufferobject/
void OpenGlBufferItemRenderer::synchronize(QQuickFramebufferObject *item)
{
    OpenGlBufferItem *openGlBufferItem = static_cast<OpenGlBufferItem*>(item);

    std::cout << "synchronize called " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "starting new renderer for uri " << this-> uri << std::endl;

    MediaStream* camera1 = new MediaStream(this->uri);
    camera1->setFrameUpdater((FrameUpdater *) this);
    //TODO: put mutex on std::cout of this thread
    //TODO: make this thread actualy run here instead of on a thread, I guess.
    boost::thread mediaThread(&MediaStream::run, camera1);
}

OpenGlBufferItem::OpenGlBufferItem(){}

void OpenGlBufferItemRenderer::updateData(unsigned char**data, int frameWidth, int frameHeight)
{
    this->frameWidth = frameWidth;
    this->frameHeight = frameHeight;
    //Before first render, datas pointer isn't even created yet
    if (!firstFrameReceived) {
        datas[0] = new unsigned char[frameWidth*frameHeight];   //Y
        datas[1] = new unsigned char[frameWidth*frameHeight/4]; //U
        datas[2] = new unsigned char[frameWidth*frameHeight/4]; //V
        firstFrameReceived = true;
    } else {
        memcpy(datas[0], data[0], frameWidth*frameHeight);
        memcpy(datas[1], data[1], frameWidth*frameHeight/4);
        memcpy(datas[2], data[2], frameWidth*frameHeight/4);
    }
}

QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer *OpenGlBufferItem::createRenderer() const
{
    //std::cout << "createRenderer called ------------------------" << std::endl;
    return new OpenGlBufferItemRenderer(this->uri);
}
```

Here's [main.qml](https://github.com/lucaszanella/orwell/blob/57a2dab0dd770dde7f8c96ed3f7ea8672cc88f81/qt/main.qml):

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import OpenGlBufferQtQuick 1.0

Grid {
    columns: 2
    spacing: 2    
    width: 1280
    height: 720
    OpenGlBufferQtQuick {
        width: 640
        height: 360
        uri: "rtsp://admin:123456@192.168.0.103:10554/tcp/av0_0"
    }
    OpenGlBufferQtQuick {
        width: 640
        height: 360
        uri: "rtsp://admin:123456@192.168.0.101:10554/tcp/av0_0"
    }
    OpenGlBufferQtQuick {
        width: 640
        height: 360
        uri: "rtsp://admin:123456@192.168.0.104:10554/tcp/av0_0"
    }
    OpenGlBufferQtQuick {
        width: 640
        height: 360
        uri: "rtsp://admin:123456@192.168.1.43:10554/tcp/av0_0"
    }

}
```

As you can see, I'm calling 4 different camera streams, but the stream from the first camera invades the space of the other streams, even though each stream is a completely different object.

Also, the image is RED. I used almost the same code to render using class `OpenGlVideoQtQuickRenderer : public QObject, protected QOpenGLFunctions` and it works without any red screen or opengl invading the other space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I payed someone to help me and the problem was that the texture shader wasn't activated. These are the changes:

https://github.com/lucaszanella/orwell/commit/b2882768badb16e4334bc2bd0371611221283e97#diff-b089e4d46edc159fb6e7de932e64219b

Basically:

```
GLint originTextureUnit;
        f->glGetIntegerv(GL_ACTIVE_TEXTURE, &originTextureUnit);
```

and

```
 f->glActiveTexture(originTextureUnit);
```

however I don't still understand why the texture wasn't activated.